# How to remove hypermedia elements from representations produced by Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

When using Spring Data for my REST API, the responses returned currently include the `_links` field:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
  "users": [
    {
      "imageUrl": "some_image_url",
      "name": "some name",
      "id": "57420b2a0d31bb6cef4ee8e9",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/57420b2a0d31bb6cef4ee8e9"
        },
        "user": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/57420b2a0d31bb6cef4ee8e9{?projection}",
          "templated": true
        }
      }
    },
...
```

Is there a way to produce output, such that the `_links` field is hidden? e.g.:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
  "users": [
    {
      "imageUrl": "some_image_url",
      "name": "some name",
      "id": "57420b2a0d31bb6cef4ee8e9",
    },
...
```

I find that because I am exposing the `id` field, `_links` are not really necessary, and mostly just clutter up my responses.

Comment: How is the client supposed to know where to find the user without the link?

Comment: @OliverGierke I have exposed the `id` field in the response.

Comment: What does the client do with a plain String that's not a URI?

Comment: @OliverGierke I am using this API in my android app, and I am using Retrofit. All requests going through it already have the endpoint (`http://the_host:port/`) defined, so all I need is the /user/{id}. The /user/ part is defined in the method I am using (`getUser()`). So all is required for me is the ID field, so I can call `getUser(id)`.

Comment: So you're client is constructing URIs on its own. That's breaking a fundamental concept of REST (see http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Spring Data REST is build on the assumption that you want to build a REST API (hence the name), not just a HTTP/JSON one. Or at least, that you can live with it exposing these special traits. If you want to build clients that break with these principles, that's fine. Just don't expect the framework to make the wrong things easy/possible .

Comment: @OliverGierke that makes sense. I guess I have more to learn about REST.  Indeed, I can have the _links without any real issues, and it seems with some further reading I will understand the benefit of them better. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I've left a few more pointers about key design decisions in my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't. Hypermedia is a fundamental trait of REST APIs and Spring Data REST heavily uses it to allow you to build clients that can use the links present in the responses to navigate to related resources.

Of course you can dumb down your clients to not make use of that information but that will lead to a much tighter coupling (as you can't change the URIs on the server side anymore, your clients expects to talk to a dedicated server whereas with hypermedia you can just point it to a different server etc.).

In contrast to a lot of other self-proclaimed REST frameworks out there, one of the key aspects of the framework's design is to respect the fundamental principles in REST and explicitly leverage them. Or at least, don't create incentives to easily break them. This is clearly expressed in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#intro-chapter) and on the [project website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/). Find out more about key design decisions in [this presentation on Spring Data REST](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/spring-data-rest-repositories-meet-hypermedia), and [this one on Domain-Driven Design & REST](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/domain-driven-design-and-rest-1).